# rvest scrape from a specified column in a table

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape the club played for by football players in lists of games (e.g. for Alan Shearer at http://www.transfermarkt.com/alan-shearer/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/3110/wettbewerb/GB1, specifically in table #3, the hughe one titled "premier league")

Annoyingly the club in the "For" column of the table is encoded as a picture with the class "tiny_wappen". I can scrape these and put them into a data.frame with

```
link <- "http://www.transfermarkt.com/alan-shearer/leistungsdatendetails/spieler/3110/wettbewerb/GB1"
    UrlPage <- read_html (link)
    Node <- UrlPage %>% html_nodes("table") %>% `[`(3) %>% html_nodes("img.tiny_wappen")
    ClubFor <- data.frame(html_attr(Node, "alt"))
```

but some (roughly one in every five) of the clubs in the adjacent column (vs.) is also in this image class so I get a list dotted with clubs played against. Is there someway to specify a column of the table to scrape from (or some other cleverer way to achieve what I want)?

pre-emptive thanks as always,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `xpaths` to grab the fourth cell of every row

```
Node <- UrlPage %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='main']/div[9]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/a/img") 

ClubFor = Node %>%
  html_attr("alt") %>%
  data.frame()
```